# Как сложить два разных, по размеру, вектора в R

Tags: массивы, r, вектор

Допустим есть вектора:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Как сложить все элементы из a с элементами b циклично, чтобы на выходе был вот такой результат:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 12
```

Если можно срезами, то было бы замечательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для сложения двух векторов (любой длины) служит оператор `+`:

```
> rep(1, 8) + 1:4
[1] 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5
```

в случае, когда длина большего вектора не кратна длине меньшего, вдобавок к результату получаем предупреждение:

```
> rep(1, 10) + 1:4
 [1] 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3
Warning message:
In rep(1, 10) + 1:4 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

при желании вывод предупреждения можно подавить, например, с помощью функции `suppressWarnings()`:

```
> suppressWarnings(rep(1, 10) + 1:4)
 [1] 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

я бы делал так:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
a+rep(b, ceiling(length(a)/length(b)))[1:length(a)]
 [1]  2  4  6  8  6  8 10 12 10 12
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,  так и думал, что без округления не обойтись

Answer (score 1):

чтобы сложить надо использовать плюс a+b

https://ideone.com/rVcBu9

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(a+b)
```

Comment: тот, кто минусует, попробовал сам произвести сложение? результат-то верный. ну, да, получаете вдобавок предупреждение «longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length», но результат-то тоже получаете. а если смущает предупреждение, так можно и заглушить его: `suppressWarnings(a+b)`

Comment: Ого, я если честно думал, что такое сообщение даёт краш, а не варнинг, тогда извиняюсь за свою некомпетентность. Спасибо большое.